# Not able to work with mysql stored procedure in ssrs

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, mysql-error-1064, ssrs-tablix

I am not able to work with MySQL stored procedures in SSRS.

While using Mysql queries dataaset get created successfully. but if want to fetch data from stored procedures with parameter i get this error.

> ERROR [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(a) Driver][mysqld-8.0.13]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ims_data.GetUploadStatus' at line 1
>   [image: Passing Parameter]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: SQL Server (MSSQL) is not the same as MySQL!.. Pretty sure "**SQL Server** Reporting Services" (SSRS) is meant to only work for SQL Server (MSSQL)

Answer (score 3):

ODBC does not support named parameters.  you need to use `?` for parameters

You can try

```
CALL ims_data.GetUploadStatus(?)
```

or

```
EXEC ('CALL ims_data.GetUploadStatus(?)', @p_period) AT MySQL  (Linked Server Name)
```

Comment: Hi @Simonare

I even tried that too..
`CALL ims_data.GetUploadStatus(?) `

But that is returning only 1 record.